# How do I tell Django to not create a table for an M2M related field?

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

I'm using this little jewel of a Django code snippet to edit a ManyToManyField from both directions:

```
class ManyToManyField_NoSyncdb(models.ManyToManyField):  
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  
        super(ManyToManyField_NoSyncdb, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.creates_table = False  

class Job(models.Model):  
    persons = ManyToManyField_NoSyncdb( Person, blank=True, db_table='person_jobs' )
```

(snippet details [here](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1295/))

It lets me select all the persons in a given job from the jobs form and inversely lets me select all the jobs for a person from the persons form and updates the single jobs_persons table in both cases.

Upon moving from Django 1.0 to 1.2, however, syncdb now generates a duplicate table error because creates_table is evidently no longer a supported property in the base class.

Is there another way to instruct Django 1.2 not to create a table for a RelatedField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you want to have access to the ManyToMany in both models in the Admin, currently the *official* solution is to use [inlinemodel](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) for the second model. I had also this same problem/need just a few days ago. And I was not really satisfied with the *inlinemodel* solution (heavy in DB queries if you have a lot of entries, cannot use the `filter_horizontal` widget, etc.).

The solution I found (that's working with Django 1.2+ and `syncdb`) is this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    groups = models.ManyToManyField('Group', through='UserGroups')

class Group(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField('User', through='UserGroups')

class UserGroups(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    group_id = models.ForeignKey(Group)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'app_user_group'
        auto_created = User
```

See ticket [897](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/897) for more info.

Unfortunately, if you're using [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) you will have to remove the creation of the `app_user_group` table in every migration file created automatically.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm on Django 1.3.1, and I followed your example (except my models are in different modules, but that shouldn't matter I don't think). Anyways, when I do something like userObj.groups, I am getting an error where Django is apparently trying to use "User" as a string, rather than figuring out that it's an object. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Without seeing your code, I don't have an idea. Normally it should work (it's still working for me in Django 1.3, didn't test 1.3.1). The problem could be that your models are in different modules (I don't remember enough how model resolution works when it's a string).  Did you check the ticket #897. There's 2 newer solutions. The last one do the same thing as mine but it's pretty clean and simple.

Answer (score 2):

The "managed" meta option for models might be helpful.  From http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/options/#managed

> If a model with managed=False contains
>   a ManyToManyField that points to
>   another unmanaged model, then the
>   intermediate table for the
>   many-to-many join will also not be
>   created. However, the intermediary
>   table between one managed and one
>   unmanaged model will be created.
>
> If you need to change this default
>   behavior, create the intermediary
>   table as an explicit model (with
>   managed set as needed) and use the
>   ManyToManyField.through attribute to
>   make the relation use your custom
>   model.

Answer (score 1):

Let me post the [new solution](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/897#comment:28) in Django's ticket #897, which mention by Etienne too. It work well in Django 1.2.

```
class Test1(models.Model):
    tests2 = models.ManyToManyField('Test2', blank=True)

class Test2(models.Model):
    tests1 = models.ManyToManyField(Test1, through=Test1.tests2.through, blank=True)
```